# Websocket: server disconnect vs page navigation

Tags: javascript, websocket

I implemented reconnection logic when ws is disconnected at client side (onclose), for example, when I restart WS server all clients shows info about reconnection and starts to re-establish connection. But when user just clisks on any link at the page, that code is also code, and before leaving the page user sees something like "Reconnecting...". Is it possible to distinguish these two events somehow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it making a delay before starting reconnect, so it is enought for browser to switch to another page and user is not noticed :)